# Simply add an object to an empty array using action creators, redux, and thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, state

I want to simply add a new 'client' to my empty `clientList` located in my `clientReducer`. I can see everything is working clearly because when I `console.log(state)` in my `clientReducer`, I can see the information from the input has gone through the dispatch, the action creator and is now in the reducer. My issue is this chunk of code here... I am trying to keep adding clients to  my redux store.

I tried using `this.setState({})` but it doesn't read it.

Here is the `clientActions`:

```
export const addClient = (client) => {
    return(dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({type: 'ADD CLIENT', client})
    }
}
```

Here is the `clientReducer`:

```
const initState = {
    clientList: []
}

const clientReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'ADD CLIENT' : 
            let clientList =  [...state.clientList, action.client];
            this.setState({
              clientList : clientList
            })
            return state;
        
        default : return state;
    }
}    

export default clientReducer
```

Comment: I will be using firebase and adding it to the firestore later, but I want to know how to do this just using redux and action creators. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do `setState` inside reducer instead just return the updated state.

```
const clientReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'ADD CLIENT' : 
            let clientList =  [...state.clientList, action.client];
            return {
              ...state,
              clientList : clientList
            }

        default : return state;
    }
}    

export default clientReducer
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly